# query to find number of empty tables in my schema name HR

Tags: oracle

I want to find the number of empty tables in my schema hr and i have written a code for it:

```
set serveroutput on;


Declare
d Number;
c varchar2(25);
cursor c1 is SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OWNER = 'HR';

Begin
 for r in c1
Loop
select count(*) into d
from (r.object_name);
if (d = 0) then
dbms_output.put_line(r.object_name||'is Empty');
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

but its throwing error at this line from (r.object_name). can anyone help me in this?

Comment: You'll need to provide much more, specific, context for anyone to help you

Comment: Google "dynamic SQL"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL with table name as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211749/dynamic-sql-with-table-name-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 3):

Querying `dba_tables.num_rows` is not reliable as that is an *estimate*. If the table has never been analyzed, it might not reflect the correct row count.

Dynamic SQL is also not required for this. Based on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705088/330315) that calculates the row count for all tables, you can simply add a where condition:

```
select table_name
from (
  select table_name, 
         to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as row_count
   from all_tables
   where owner = 'HR'
)
where row_count = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) (`execute immediate`) for that:

```
declare
  d number;
  v_sql varchar2(1000);

  cursor c1 is select object_name 
    from all_objects 
    where object_type = 'TABLE' and owner = 'HR';

begin
  for r in c1 loop
      v_sql := 'select count(*) from HR.'||r.object_name;
      execute immediate v_sql into d;
      if d = 0 then
          dbms_output.put_line(r.object_name||' is empty');
      end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: its still throwing an error table or view does not exist

Comment: Add owner: `v_sql := 'select count(*) from HR.'||r.object_name;`

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle , you can use below query.

```
select    count(*) from    dba_tables  where    OWNER = 'XXXX' and num_rows =0;
```